# controlling behavior of drag-and-drop into Emacs on MacOS

Tags: macos, emacs

My MacOS version of Emacs inserts contents of the file into current buffer instead of opening it as a new buffer. I want it to open a new buffer on file drag-and-drop, any idea how to fix that?

GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set drag and drop to do anything you want by binding `ns-drag-file`.  It will of course be a different event on different platforms.  Perhaps surprisingly you can find this by `C-h k` and then dragging a file to emacs.

Answer (score 3):

upgrade to emacs 24.1, just released, whose drag&drop behavior has changed as you desire.